# FlyingSaucer LTR/RTL/BiDi issue with arabic text

Tags: java, pdf, arabic, bidi, xhtmlrenderer

I'm using flying saucer xhtmlrenderer for building pdf documents. Everything worked fine until now - now we should generate arabic text inside pdf.
Xhtmlrenderer is rendering Arabic text in reverse order.

I've read somewhere on internet (maybe on their own site) that xhtmlrenderer does not support bidi/rtl.
But IText itself contains examples to work with arabic and hebrew via ColumnText and PdfPTable (sources can be found here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextpdf/files/Examples/examples-155/examples-155.zip/download - arabic_hebrew.java), and those work fine.

I tried to use itext api in xhtmlrenderer's ReplacedElementFactory/ITextReplacedElement, but could not find good examples for positioning elements.
Does anyone tried to do this? Or maybe there is a simplier (or at least working) solution?

Comment: if someone is interesting in topic, here is link for google group on this: http://groups.google.com/group/flying-saucer-users/browse_thread/thread/9f409fb987e943a2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I'm able to print arabic text in rtl/ltr using flying saucer.
In my code I'm giving width and alignment for every arabic text block, but in general it works fine.
(*Edited*) Code is large to print it down here, please find the code on Google groups, the links are in the comments.

Comment: hi askar. could you please share your code? thanks in advanced

Comment: @Hamid The answer with link was deleted because of no-links-policy. They are here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/flying-saucer-users/n0CfuYfpQ6I/-PvsHoRI9jwJ

Comment: @sala please check the link i gave in the previous comment, it's still working.

Comment: This response since 2011 am asking if the Lib did some refactoring to deal with the arabic without adding the provided solution

Answer (score 2):

Same issue I was facing, only solution i can find out was using arial fonts
import/add arial.ttf and arialbold.ttf files in resources folder of your project.

```
            OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
        ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
        // renderer.getFontResolver().addFont("/fonts/arialbold.ttf",
        // BaseFont.IDENTITY_H,BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
        renderer.getFontResolver().addFont("/fonts/arial.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
        renderer.getFontResolver().addFont("/fonts/arialbold.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);

        // SharedContext sharedContext = renderer.getSharedContext();
        // sharedContext.setPrint(true);
        // sharedContext.setInteractive(false);
        // sharedContext.setReplacedElementFactory(new B64ImgReplacedElementFactory());
        // sharedContext.getTextRenderer().setSmoothingThreshold(0);

        renderer.setDocumentFromString(content);
        renderer.layout();
        renderer.createPDF(outputStream);
        renderer.finishPDF();
        outputStream.close();
```

in your css use

```
html, body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: Arial, Arial Bold;
 font-size: 10px;
 line-height: 14px;
}
```

Comment: @ZainElabidine you can manage it with RTL direction, even with that, there were space issues, so i switched to Jasper which works like charm.